# Basic Caesar Cipher in Swift 3.1

Tags: beginner, swift, caesar-cipher, swift3

I have been learning Swift for the past day and thought I'd try a basic problem where I can do String manipulation. I am only on pg.100 of the Swift Programming Language on iBooks. Compared to python it seems to be quite difficult to actually modify individual characters as Swift is strongly typed/type safe.

> A Caesar cipher is used to encrypt a String by shifting each letter by x, where x is an integer, and replaces each letter withe the shifted letter. So `encrypt("AB", 2)` becomes `"BC"`

If anyone could point where I can reduce the number of lines or an easier way of doing/or idioms I have missed that'd be just what I am looking for.

```
import Cocoa

func encrypt(message: String, shift: Int) -> String {

    let scalars = Array(message.unicodeScalars)
    let unicodePoints = scalars.map({x in Character(UnicodeScalar(Int(x.value) + shift)!)})

    return String(unicodePoints)
}

let message = "Attack at dawn"
print(encrypt(message: message, shift: 2))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `unicodeScalars` view of the Swift `String` is a good start,
but the code can be simplified:

- There is no need to create an array first, you can call `map`
  directly on the `unicodeScalars` collection.
- The conversion to `Character` is not needed, the array of shifted
  unicode scalars can be converted directly back to a string
  (attribution to [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45294271/convert-array-of-unicodescalar-into-string-in-swift/45296440#45296440)).

Also the variable name `unicodePoints` is misleading, because that
is an array of `Character` in your code.

Your method then becomes

```
func encrypt(message: String, shift: Int) -> String {
    let unicodeScalars = message.unicodeScalars.map { UnicodeScalar(Int($0.value) + shift)! }
    return String(String.UnicodeScalarView(unicodeScalars))
}
```

However, this is probably not yet what you want. Example:

```
let message = "Attack at dawn"
print(encrypt(message: message, shift: 2))    // Cvvcem"cv"fcyp
print(encrypt(message: message, shift: 10))   // K~~kmu*k~*nkx
```

*All* characters are shifted by the given amount so that a space
becomes a quotation mark, and some letters are transformed to non-letters. Also

```
print(encrypt(message: message, shift: -100))
```

crashes at runtime, because the unicode scalar value is shifted to
an invalid value.

The traditional Caesar Cipher transforms only letters in the range
A...Z, and *rotates* them, so that shifting "Z" by 2 becomes "B".
Lowercase letters can be transformed to uppercase, but other characters
are usually ignored (either removed or left unchanged).

Here is a possible implementation with an inner function
`shiftLetter()` which transforms a single letter.
This inner function is used as argument in

```
msg.unicodeScalars.map(shiftLetter)
```

to transform the entire String:

```
func encrypt(message: String, shift: Int) -> String {

    func shiftLetter(ucs: UnicodeScalar) -> UnicodeScalar {
        let firstLetter = Int(UnicodeScalar("A").value)
        let lastLetter = Int(UnicodeScalar("Z").value)
        let letterCount = lastLetter - firstLetter + 1

        let value = Int(ucs.value)
        switch value {
        case firstLetter...lastLetter:
            // Offset relative to first letter:
            var offset = value - firstLetter
            // Apply shift amount (can be positive or negative):
            offset += shift
            // Transform back to the range firstLetter...lastLetter:
            offset = (offset % letterCount + letterCount) % letterCount
            // Return corresponding character:
            return UnicodeScalar(firstLetter + offset)!
        default:
            // Not in the range A...Z, leave unchanged:
            return ucs
        }
    }

    let msg = message.uppercased()
    return String(String.UnicodeScalarView(msg.unicodeScalars.map(shiftLetter)))
}
```

Examples:

```
let message = "Attack at dawn"
print(encrypt(message: message, shift: 2))    // CVVCEM CV FCYP
print(encrypt(message: message, shift: 10))   // KDDKMU KD NKGX
print(encrypt(message: message, shift: -100)) // EXXEGO EX HEAR
```

Comment: Great review, cheers!