# HackerRank Caesar Cipher, not using map, filter, reduce, regex

Tags: programming-challenge, swift, caesar-cipher

Julius Caesar protected his confidential information by encrypting it in a cipher. Caesar's cipher rotated every letter in a string by a fixed number, `K`, making it unreadable by his enemies. Given a string,`S` , and a number, `K` , encrypt `S`.

Note: The cipher only encrypts letters; symbols, such as `-`, remain unencrypted.

```
func cipher(messageToCipher: String, k: Int)-> String{
  var  eMessage = ""
  let arr = messageToCipher.characters.map { String($0) }
  for ch in arr {
    for code in String(ch).utf8 { 
        if (65<=code && code<=90) || (97<=code && code<=122) {
              if k > 26{
                    let value =  k % 26 == 0 ? k / 26 : k % 26 
                    var pCode  = ((Int(code))  + (value))  

                    if (pCode  > 122 && (97<=code && code<=122)) || (pCode  > 90 && (65<=code && code<=90)) {
                        pCode = pCode - 26
                    }

                   let s = String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(pCode)))
                   eMessage = eMessage + s
                }else
                {
                    var pCode  = Int(code) + k

                    if (pCode  > 122 && (97<=code && code<=122)) || (pCode  > 90 && (65<=code && code<=90)) {
                        pCode = pCode - 26
                    }

                   let s = String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(pCode)))
                   eMessage = eMessage + s
                }

        }
        else{        
            eMessage = eMessage + ch
        }
    }   
  }
  return eMessage
}


print(cipher(messageToCipher: "abc", k: 2) )
```

I solved this way and it was passed all test cases.

More information on this problem: [Caesar Cipher](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/caesar-cipher-1/problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Enumerating UTF-8 characters:* Your code uses two nested loops to encrypt letters
(based on the UTF-8 code):

```
var  eMessage = ""
let arr = messageToCipher.characters.map { String($0) }
for ch in arr {
    for code in String(ch).utf8 {
        if (65<=code && code<=90) || (97<=code && code<=122) {
            // ... translate `code` and append to `eMessage` ...
        }
        else{
            eMessage = eMessage + ch
        }
    }
}
```

This is unnecessary complicated and has an unwanted side effect if the message contains
non-ASCII characters (which are encoded as 2 or more UTF-8 code units):

```
print(cipher(messageToCipher: "ä €  ", k: 2) )
// ää €€€
```

This could be solved by adding a `break` in the else-case. The better solution is to
enumerate the UTF-8 code units directly:

```
var encoded: [UInt8] = []
for code in messageToCipher.utf8 {
    if (65<=code && code<=90) || (97<=code && code<=122) {
        // ... translate `code` and append to `encoded` ...
    }
    else{
        encoded.append(code)
    }
}
return String(bytes: encoded, encoding: .utf8)!
```

*Code duplication:* There is some duplicate code in

```
            if k > 26{
                let value =  k % 26 == 0 ? k / 26 : k % 26
                var pCode  = ((Int(code))  + (value))
                if (pCode  > 122 && (97<=code && code<=122)) || (pCode  > 90 && (65<=code && code<=90)) {
                    pCode = pCode - 26
                }
                let s = String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(pCode)))
                eMessage = eMessage + s
            }else
            {
                var pCode  = Int(code) + k
                if (pCode  > 122 && (97<=code && code<=122)) || (pCode  > 90 && (65<=code && code<=90)) {
                    pCode = pCode - 26
                }
                let s = String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(pCode)))
                eMessage = eMessage + s
            }
```

which is not necessary. The if-part works for the case `k <= 26` as well.

*Exceptional key values:* The special handling of the case `k % 26 == 0` causes
unexpected results:

```
print(cipher(messageToCipher: "abc xyz ABC XYZ", k: 26) ) // abc xyz ABC XYZ
print(cipher(messageToCipher: "abc xyz ABC XYZ", k: 52) ) // cde zab CDE ZAB
```

and is not needed. *Negative* key values are not handled at all:

```
print(cipher(messageToCipher: "abc xyz ABC XYZ", k: -2) )   // _`a vwx ?@A VWX
print(cipher(messageToCipher: "abc xyz ABC XYZ", k: -200) )
// Fatal error: Negative value is not representable
```

Both issues can be solved by computing the *remainder* of `k` modulo 26, as a number
in the range 0...25:

```
var value = k % 26
if value < 0 { value += 26 }
```

In addition, this computation can be done *once,* before entering the loop.

*Other issues:*

- I would use some different argument/variable names, e.g. `message` instead of 
  `messageToCipher` (it is clear from the context and the function name that this string
  should be encrypted), or  `key` instead of `k`.
- There are unnecessary parentheses, e.g. in

  ```
  var pCode  = ((Int(code))  + (value))
  ```
- The usage of white space is not consistent, e.g. in

  ```
  if (pCode  > 122 && (97<=code && code<=122)) || (pCode  > 90 && (65<=code && code<=90)) {
  ```

Summarizing the suggestions so far, we have

```
func cipher(message: String, key: Int) -> String {

    var offset = key % 26
    if offset < 0 { offset += 26 }

    var encoded: [UInt8] = []
    for code in message.utf8 {
        if (65 <= code && code <= 90) || (97 <= code && code <= 122) {
                var pCode  = Int(code) + offset
                if (pCode > 122 && (97 <= code && code <= 122)) || (pCode > 90 && (65 <= code && code <= 90)) {
                    pCode -= 26
                }
                encoded.append(UInt8(pCode))
        } else {
            encoded.append(code)
        }
    }
    return String(bytes: encoded, encoding: .utf8)!
}
```

*Make it functional:* If the encryption of a single character is moved to a separate
function then one can apply this to the UTF-8 view with `map()`:

```
func cipher(message: String, key: Int) -> String {

    var offset = key % 26
    if offset < 0 { offset += 26 }

    func utf8encrypt(code: UInt8) -> UInt8 {
        // ... compute and return encrypted character ...
    }

    return String(bytes: message.utf8.map(utf8encrypt), encoding: .utf8)!
}
```

*Further suggestions:*

- Use a switch-statement with range patterns instead of the
  if-conditions:

  ```
  switch code {
  case 65...90:
      // ...
  case 97...122:
      // ...
  default:
      // ...
  }
  ```
- Use constants instead of the literal numbers, e.g.

  ```
  let letter_A = 65
  let letter_Z = 90
  let letter_a = 97
  let letter_z = 122
  ```

so that a future reader of your code does not have to guess what the numbers stand for.

Comment: @NazmulHasan: You are welcome! – (You might also be interested in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/172017/basic-caesar-cipher-in-swift-3-1, where that "encryption" is done based on Unicode scalars instead of UTF-8 code units.)